# How would I convert separate digits to an actual number?

Tags: programming-languages

In Dr. Racket, how would I combine the digits w, x, y, z to wxyz (for example 3, 7, 8, 9 to 3,789)?
I haven't gotten very far on this:

(define digits-to-numbers w x y z)

Comment: Coding questions and requests for how to do something in a particular programming language are off-topic here.

Comment: (When posting this to an appropriate, but otherwise unsuspecting community, mention the [Racket Language](https://docs.racket-lang.org/). ([stack**overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) seems to have dropped the drracket tag - considering [tag:racket] enough?))